# Unity c# how to compare text from button array with another int array?

Tags: c#, arrays, user-interface, unity-game-engine, button

i have two arrays. one of ui buttons - with child TextMeshProUGUI and another array of int.
i want to compare each element of button (text) array with int array when all buttons have new value assigned to them.

`userInputs[]` holds buttons to get user's input from given 8 options to answer question.
`correctAnswers[]` holds all correct answers.

i am able to check if all buttons got values assigned. then i am checking answers. here i want button image to change green if correct and red if incorrect.
Not able to understand how to compare? please help

```
public void CheckAnswers()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    // for (i = 0; i < userInputs.Length; i++)
    {

        foreach (Button userInput in userInputs)
            if (userInputs[i].GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text 
  == correctAnswers[j].ToString())
            {
                userInput.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
            }
            else
            {
                {
                    userInput.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, you have added the whole code here, can you please do an edit and show the necessary snippets only. this is bit confusing and also `userAnswers` is not found in your code

Comment: @sujith can you please have a look at `public bool CheckAnswers()` please

Comment: i put entire code just to show my working. sorry for typing error its `userInputs` i changed it

Comment: as you know how to set the button text what exactly is confusing you about checking if a button matches an answer

Comment: @BugFinder  i want to wait till all 4 buttons got new values assigned from 8 given options. then i want to compare them with correctanswers. on  check i want correct answered button to change to green else red.

Comment: @BugFinder i have changed `CheckAnswers()` now i get green or red but all of them are changing when i am answering just a single question. for example if i answer 1st question correct all buttons get green if incorrect all buttons get red. it doesnt wait till all 4 questions are answered

Comment: because you run a foreach but then use the fixed variable i to do the test

Comment: how do i fix it? please

Comment: Dont use `int i` and `in j` in `foreach` loop. They are incremented by 1 everytime.

Comment: @SaadAneesif i dont use i and j then how do i compare two arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change loops in your `CheckAnswers()`. You are taking `foreach` loop for `userInputs` and still incrementing it with an `int` It should be like this.

```
        foreach (Button userInput in userInputs)
    {
 for (i = 0; i < userInputs.Length; i++)
            {
                    if (userInput.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text 
        == correctAnswers[i].ToString())
                    {
                        userInput.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        {
                            userInput.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
                        }
                    }
    }
        }
```

Becareful because you could get error for `Argument out of range exception` if your userInputs is less than your correctAnswers array. I hope this helps you.

Comment: i have implemented above code. but it is changing value of only last element of array.rest all buttons get red even if answer is correct.

Comment: also it is changing color of all answer buttons even if i answer only one question

Comment: Show me your UI elements please. Let me understand what you are doing.

Comment: sure .added image in my question. please check. thanks

Comment: Thanks. As per the picture, you have 8 buttons with possible answers which will change color to red or green according to the user's input. Right? And above that what happens with the "?" button? Does it show anything?

Comment: @ Saad those 8 buttons show possible answers.first user will have to select respective yellow button to answer question then click any button from those 8. whichever button is clicked that value is assigned to previously selected yellow button. when all 4 questions r answered then i want to change color of each yellow button to show its correct or not. using green and red

Comment: How do you know which yellow button have been pressed? Do you save it somewhere? Which method run when you hit on Yellow button? Sorry but your explanation is not clear and now i think you comparing arrays as per your need.

Comment: @  Saad. user will have to select specific yellow button to answer it. `assignToYellowButton` this function will assign value of of selected answer to the yellow button. yes i have stored those 4 yellow buttons in userInputs array and trying to compare with correctanswers array

Comment: You are not calling `selectedYellowButton` anywhere in the code to change its color. And in the loop you are calling only inputs button and comparing it to correc answers array. You have to compare `selectedYellowButton` with the inputs button